# How to solve $x^{\log_3(x)} \geq \frac{1}{27}$

Tags: logarithms

How to solve this? My problem is to solve:

$$x^{\log_3(x-4)} \ge \frac{1}{27}.$$

The log base is $3$.

Comment: Is that exponent $(\log x) - 4$ or $\log(x - 4)$?

Comment: If it is $\log(x) - 4$, then you should get a quadratic: $\log_{3}(x)(\log_{3}(x)-4) \geq -3$, since $\log$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: log(x-4) and base is 3

Comment: Take $\log_3$ from both sides.

Comment: @Lucian This user wants to determine $x^{\log(x)}$

Comment: @NasuSama The original question said "my problem in solve $x^{\log x}$". Given that he then states an inequality for $x^{\log x}$ which happens to have a very clean solution for $x$ (see the answer below), I think it is fair to assume he just wanted to solve for $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestions above, we take the log base 3 of both sides to get
$(\log_{3}x)(\log_{3}x-4)\ge-3$, using the fact that $f(x)=\log_{3}x$ is increasing.  Substituting $u=\log_{3}x$ gives $u(u-4)\ge-3$ so $u^2-4u+3\ge0$.

Then $(u-3)(u-1)\ge0$, so either $u\le1$ or $u\ge3$.

If $u\le1$, then $\log_{3}x\le1$ so $0<x\le3$.

If $u\ge3$, then $\log_{3}x\ge3$ so $x\ge27$.

Therefore the solution is given by $(0,3]\cup[27,\infty)$.